# Куда лучше вывести ответ json на android

Tags: android, json

Я получаю ответ на запрос в формате json, и нужно его как то привести в читаемый вид. Куда проще его выводить и каков принцип?

Comment: Нужно распарсить полученный json, потом выводите куда вам нужно. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак вы получили строковый результат. Теперь из него надо сделать JSON объект.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(строковый_результат);
```

Для получения конкретного значения типа `String` по ключу:

```
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("ключ_string");
```

Для получения конкретного значения типа `boolean` по ключу:

```
boolean aJsonBoolean = jObject.getBoolean("ключ_boolean");
```

Для получения конкретного значения типа `integer` по ключу:

```
int aJsonInteger = jObject.getInt("ключ_integer");
```

Для получения конкретного значения типа `long` по ключу:

```
long aJsonLong = jObject.getBoolean("ключ_long");
```

Для получения конкретного значения типа `double` по ключу:

```
double aJsonDouble = jObject.getDouble("ключ_double");
```

Для получения конкретного значения массива `JSONArray` по ключу:

```
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("ключ_array");
```

Для получения элементов массива:

```
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("ключ1");
        String oneObjectsItem2 = oneObject.getString("ключ2");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // обработка исключений на случай не нахождения конкретного ключа
    }
}
```

[Почитать про JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)
 / [Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/1616443)

Answer (score 3):

вообще красивый вариант

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 1):

Есть удобная библиотека https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/